# ssh-agent not remembering identity and password

Tags: ssh, zsh, ssh-agent

I have zsh running on my Debian. It has the following lines in my .zshrc included:

```
plugins=(git ssh-agent)

zstyle :omz:plugins:ssh-agent helper ksshaskpass
zstyle :omz:plugins:ssh-agent identities id_odin id_git
```

My SSH Key "id_odin" has a password. Everytime I connect to a server, it keeps asking for the passphrase.
I tried to store the password for the agent so it will be remembered on reboot, but this unfortunately doesn't work.

When I try to add it to the keychain I get the following error:

```
ssh-add -K .ssh/id_odin
Enter PIN for authenticator: 
Provider "internal" returned failure -4
Unable to load resident keys: device not found
```

I have no idea what the exact PIN for the authenticator might be.
Normal adding works but won't be remembered.

```
Enter passphrase for .ssh/id_odin: 
Identity added: .ssh/id_odin (odin admin)
```